# What is $g^1_3$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to find the definition of $g^1_3$ in algebraic geometry Hartshorne's book, anyone who is used with this book could help me to find this definition?

Thanks

[image]

*Remark:* this extract is from page 345 from Hartshorne's book.

Comment: The text doesn't define $g_d^1$?

Comment: (It would also help to list the edition and page of this quote, so people can help you understand in the context of the book.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm sure it does, but I didn't find it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the page is 345, I'm going to edit my question saying the page number, thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text does define a $g^r_d$; it's on the middle of page 341.  For the sake of completeness: we say $C$ has a $g^r_d$ if it has a linear system of dimension $r$ and degree $d$.

This is a very old notation that's still in common use, even outside Hartshorne's book.

Comment: So Can I say that a curve $C$ is trigonal if it has a divisor which has a linear system $g_n^r$?